# What's the practical difference between using global and public access modifiers?

Tags: apex, access-modifier

What is the difference between global and public access modifier in apex? I tried googling but still not able to understand.. Any example will be most helpfull.. Thanks

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**PUBLIC** means the class/method/variable is visible to all code in your namespace

**GLOBAL** means the class/method/variable is visible to all code in **any** namespace

So if you're aren't developing managed packages there isn't much difference. If you are developing managed packages you'll use **GLOBAL** when you want to expose classes/methods/variables to the org that installed your package. And consequently, you would be held to keeping those classes/methods/variables available in future versions as your subscribers may have started referencing. Where as public classes/methods/variables you can remove at your leisure since you know the subscriber org won't have any references to them.

There used to be some edge cases for automated process (i.e. batches had to be global), but most of these are no longer required. However templates for batches still seem to imply you have to use global.